# Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’ on Mac even after downloading QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have installed QuickCheck using the following command stack ghci --package QuickCheck on my mac.
But still not able to load the module

````
Part1.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import Test.QuickCheck
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded. ```
````

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue by using `stack ghci` outside of a project, but it worked fine here. You might want to [edit] your question to mention how you are loading the `Part1.hs` file (was it `:l Part1.hs` after `stack ghci --package QuickCheck`, or is it part of a package you are writing?), the version of Stack and the Stackage snapshot you are using, as well as the `stack.yaml` file, if you are working within a Stack project.

Comment: It worked when I used the procedure mentioned by @eleuthere .

Comment: The procedure in that answer doesn't use Stack, but rather cabal-install (a different build tool). That's fine if you don't actually need Stack for your purposes, but otherwise you might keep running into the same problem wheneber you have to use `stack ghci`.

Answer (score 1):

I did this.

cabal update

cabal install QuickCheck --lib

ghci

import Test.QuickCheck

And I got the expected "Prelude Test.QuickCheck>". So it seems to be alright.

Comment: This question is specifically about Stack, so using `cabal install` doesn't solve it.